# How to get pass by reference to work in a function properly in C

Tags: c

The function with the pass by value works like it ought to, I believe, as it prints out the value 0 whenever I enter two numbers. However the `adderRef` (pass by reference function) doesn't work. All it prints out is "the pass by reference of c is" and that's it. There is no value or anything. I just wanted to inquire whether there was something wrong with my syntax or something....
Okay guys sorry about the question being vague and for my errors. It's my first time asking on stackoverflow and I should have been more mindful. I'm aware of my error and why I made it. I got muddled in class when my teacher was altering the code a bit and I copied it down incorrectly/ Thanks everyone for your help. Yes i was indeed quite dumb .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void adderval(int a, int b);
void adderRef(int *, int *);

int main()
{
    int a, b, c = 0;
    printf("enter two numbers.\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    adderval(a, b);
    printf("the pass by value of c is %d \n", c);
    adderRef(&a, &b);
    printf("the pass by reference of c is \n", c );
    return 0;
}

void adderRef(int *a, int *b )
{
    int c;
    c = *a + *b;
}

void adderval(int a, int b )
{
    int c;
    c = a + b;
}
```

Comment: Your way of "seeking the answer on your own" is posting a vague question on Stack Overflow with no real problem statement?

Comment: Unrelated: your compiler did *not* warn you about `printf("the pass by reference of c is \n",c );` ?? (note: no format specifier, yet you're sending an `int c` arg?) Btw,  `c` in both of those functions have *nothing* to do with the `c` in `main()`.

Comment: C doesn't have *references*, it can only be emulated. C++ on the other hand *do* have references. So you have to decide, are you programming in C or C++?

Comment: C passes everything by value.  There is no such thing as passing by reference in C.

Comment: You don't assign any value to c after init..

Comment: Check your `printf` format string, why *should* it print any value?

Comment: Don't forget to print the input values to make sure your program is reading what you think it is.  You should be checking that the `scanf()` call works.  You could add print operations in the bodies of the functions.  As it stands, the optimizer could eliminate calls to both functions since there are no useful side effects.

Answer (score -1):

corrected as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void adderval(int a,int b,int c);
void adderRef(int a,int b,int *c );


int main()
{
        int a,b,c=0;
        printf("enter two numbers.\n");
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
        adderval(a,b,c);
        printf("the pass by value of c is %d \n",c);
        adderRef(a,b,&c);
        printf("the pass by reference of c is %d \n",c );
        return 0;
}
void adderRef (int a, int b, int *c )
{
        *c = a + b;
}
void adderval (int a , int b,int c )
{
        c=a+b;
}
```

Comment: From next time please try to answer without mocking anybody. Cheers !!

Comment: What's the benefit of the argument `c` to `adderval()`?

Comment: @ameyCU ok. but it's true. and I think he should study generous in class and read book carefully and re-think the exersices before post this question .

Comment: @JonathanLeffler useless. I add this just for compare with addRef.One passed by value ,the other passed by pointer.

Comment: thanks im so sorry.. I actually now recall my teacher having this on the board but he changed it so many times that I ended up copying the wrong thing. The program doesnt have a real purpose. It was just a basic intro to teach us about pass by reference and value. Thanks again